# Access some sort of db in docker

Tags: database, docker, ddev

I've been absent to webdev for a while and trying to get up to speed with this new ddev thingy.

So I installed craft 4 via ddev and docker and such. And now I want to import an older db.

Is there some phpmyadmin available in ddev. Or how does this work? I was still using mamp and I have a hard time wrapping my head around containerization. So abstract.

Comment: If you're in Discord, it'd be interesting to hear about your experience after you've gotten used to your new ddev set up. I have absolutely no shame in saying that I've been using MAMP Pro for over a decade and am perfectly happy with it. I tried the Nitro/Docker thing for a bit, but the added complexity just wasn't worth it for me, not to mention the huge performance drain, and not being able to simultaneously have 20 projects running at the same time without constant fans running. (Definitely ditch phpmyadmin for Sequel Ace though, that's a no-brainer!)

Comment: I moved from MAMP to Nitro and then to ddev. The performance is better. The flexibility is awesome. You can just override and choose so much (on a project basis). And you can decide which projects you want to start. More projects does not equal to less performance. Also have more than 20 projects to manage. Only thing I actively miss is sendmail.

Comment: "flexibility is awesome" is a bit vague - what can you actually do that you couldn't before, or what pain points are solved? I also use Mailhog in MAMP Pro which is super useful. Stack Exchange comments maybe not the best place for this discussion however!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome back! In ddev you can use the command line to import and manage a database. Here are some options:

- If you're on a MAC and use Sequel Ace or Sequel Pro, you can use `ddev sequelpro` or `ddev sequelace` to open Sequel Ace or Pro. It will be connected to the DB of the project.
- If you do not use a software for DB management, you can use `ddev import-db` to start an interactive import wizard. Or you use one of the commands shown in the [ddev docs on import-db](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/usage/commands/#import-db)

Additionally you can have a look at the [DDEV docs on Database Management](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/usage/database-management/)

Answer (score 3):

DDEV has a command built-in to open [TablePlus](https://tableplus.com) (commercial) and connect to the database automatically:

```bash
  tableplus        Run tableplus with current project database (global shell host container command)
```

TablePlus is a nice app, too. After you install it, just run `ddev tableplus` within the project, and you're set.